# How do I configure the Ubuntu SDK to use a proxy cache?

Tags: application-development, proxy, ubuntu-sdk, cache

The Ubuntu SDK sets up emulators for me, which seems to involve a call to `click chroot` which then runs `debootstrap`. How do I pass through my proxy server settings through to `debootstrap`? I want to do all my Ubuntu development through my local proxy cache to save time and my bandwidth bill.

I tried setting the `http_proxy` environment variable before running `ubuntu-sdk`, but this doesn't seem to work.